# how to read only part of xml file using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder?

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

this is my test.xml file. i want to read only those attributes which are of class node and all of those coming under class node. like in this case attribute name="billNo". and not the root element and its attribute. how should i skip reading root element/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting started  example:

xml file:

```
<inventory>
    <book year="2000">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <isbn>0553380958</isbn>
        <price>14.95</price>
    </book>

    <book year="2005">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
        <price>5.99</price>
    </book>

    <book year="1995">
        <title>Zodiac</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <isbn>0553573862</isbn>
        <price>7.50</price>
    </book>

    <!-- more books... -->

</inventory>
```

Java code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;


try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("c:\\tmp\\my.xml"));

    // normalize text representation
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList listOfBooks = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    int totalBooks = listOfBooks.getLength();
    System.out.println("Total no of books : " + totalBooks);

    for(int i=0; i<listOfBooks.getLength() ; i++) {

        Node firstBookNode = listOfBooks.item(i);
        if(firstBookNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element firstElement = (Element)firstBookNode;                              
            System.out.println("Year :"+firstElement.getAttribute("year"));

            //-------
            NodeList firstNameList = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);

            NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("title : " + ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
        }
    }//end of for loop with s var
} catch (SAXParseException err) {
    System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
    System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());
} catch (SAXException e) {
    Exception x = e.getException ();
    ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace ();
}
```

ref : [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)